# Plotting an inequality with "plot" axis

Tags: plotting

Whenever I try to plot an inequality with "RegionPlot", all my plots come out in boxed frames. Is there a way to plot inequalities where I get my standard x and y axes crossing each other?

For example, I am trying to plot $$x^2 - y^2 \leq 1$$ and Mathematica gives me with RegionPlot

[image]

See how my x and y axes are stuck to the left of the box instead of having them cross at the origin? Anyway around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at `Options[RegionPlot]`, you'll find the following options (in red) that are set by default:

[image]

You need to change these appropriately to get the plot as you desire:

```
RegionPlot[x^2 - y^2 < 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you